# Coherence of the graphical language for pivotal categories

Tags: monoidal-categories, coherence, string-diagrams

Throughout I follow *A survey of graphical languages for monoidal categories*, Peter Selinger, [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3347).

A pivotal category is a monoidal category where each object $A$ has a dual $A^*$, together with a natural monoidal isomorphism $A\cong A^{**}$ (section 4.2 in Selinger *op. cit.*).
It (presumably) admits a graphical language where unit and counit a represented with cups and caps, and other morphisms are represented with boxes, which can be rotated:
[image: dual in pivotal category]

Again in Selinger, the following "theorem" is stated:

> **Theorem 4.14 (coherence for pivotal categories)**. A well-formed equation between morphisms in the language of pivotal categories follows from the axioms of pivotal categories if and only if it holds in the graphical language up to planar isotopy, including rotation of boxes.

However, Selinger also says that this theorem has only been proved in special cases:

> **Question:** what is the current status of the proof of this "theorem" in the general case?